# Where are my iPhone Photos?

Tags: iphone, photos, graphics, storage

My iPhone states that my photo library is 8GB.  However, I can only access about 100 photos from the phone or my Windows PC file explorer.  I want to clear up space on the phone by moving photos to PC.

Thank you!

Comment: Where does the iPhone cite 8GB of photos?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Microsoft Essentials Photo Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-live/photo-gallery)

The iPhone's folder hierarchy was never meant to be human-readable.